# how to load gridview from javascript in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, gridview

Hi i'm a beginner in jquerymobile.
Is there any possibility to load a gridview from javascript?
in which i need to load gridview from javascript.
my html page is

```
<body onload="loadGridView()">
<fieldset class="ui-grid-b" id="mygrid">
</filedset>
</body>
```

and the javascript function is

```
function loadGridview()
{
var img_grid=$("#mygrid"); 
      img_grid.append(' <div class="ui-block-a">
            <img alt="" src="images.jpg" style="width: 80px; height: 80px" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <img alt="" src="images.jpg" style="width: 80px; height: 80px" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <img alt="" src="images.jpg" style="width: 80px; height: 80px" />
            </div>');
}
```

Am i wrong or missing something?
thanks in advance.

Comment: you currently have a reputation of 1, therefore [please also take a look how stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) `When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use for example Firebug to debug your code, then you will see your errors

[image: screenshot]

the following corrected example works

```
<body onload="loadGridView()">
  <div data-role="page" id="a-page">
    <div data-role="content"
      <fieldset class="ui-grid-b" id="mygrid">
      </filedset>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /page -->

  <script>
  function loadGridView() {
    var img_grid=$("#mygrid");
    img_grid.append('<div class="ui-block-a"><img alt="" src="images.jpg" style="width: 80px; height: 80px" /></div>');
    img_grid.append('<div class="ui-block-b"><img alt="" src="images.jpg" style="width: 80px; height: 80px" /></div>');
    img_grid.append('<div class="ui-block-c"><img alt="" src="images.jpg" style="width: 80px; height: 80px" /></div>');
  };
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thx mate u helped me 2 find the solution.
sure i'll follow ur guidance.